# agregar un caracter de forma automatica a textbox mientras escribo c# form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas estoy necesitando que cuando escriba en un textbox me agregue un guion según siguiente formato (xxx-xx-xxxx).

lo he intentado desde el evento KeyUp pero me da dos errores,
primero me pone al inicio del texto,
segundo no me deja borrar,

```
private void txtNum (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
txtNum.Text += "-";
}
```

alguna sugerencia?, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿ Intentaste utilizar MaskedTextBox ? con este control puedes establecer una máscara . Por ejemplo si quieres que el usuario solamente ingrese números y los guiones se establezcan de forma automática podrías hacerlo utilizando la siguiente máscara : ####-##-####

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene un problema gravisimo.. es asp o winforms??? porque es muy pero muy pero muy diferente la respuesta!!!!

Comment: lo siento, es form C#, estaba haciendo algo más en asp, pero el problema es con los textbox en windows form

Comment: @ErickCastillo muchas gracias, con Mask pude crear ese formato.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). con este control puedes establecer una máscara . Por ejemplo si quieres que el usuario solamente ingrese números y los guiones se establezcan de forma automática podrías hacerlo utilizando la siguiente máscara : ####-##-####